# Synchronous distributed training is slow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build an Inception V3 model using synchronous distributed training. I'm using the code from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

I see that training speed doesn't improve much as I use more GPUs for training.

```
# of GPUs    Images processed/sec
1            18.88
2            33.92
4            66.48
8            85.44
16           114.8
32           116.224
64           167.104
128          319.616
```

I'm using EC2 P2 instances (p2.16xlarge). Here is more info on P2 instances: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p2/

Is this the expected speedup or is there anything I can do more than that sample code to improve speed in this synchronous distributed training?

Comment: images/sec would ideally scale linearly....you could start with timeline profiling to see where the bottlenecks are

Comment: You might also check on queue sizes; I/O may be a bottleneck?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: I got the trace (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7oulcoGSkO_TUR4d0JIM0pVTmM). But Chrome throws the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 8054387" while trying to load the file. Any idea why?

Comment: @AllenLavoie: I'm able to reproduce the problem using randomly generated fake data instead of real data (like https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/alexnet/alexnet_benchmark.py). That would suggest IO is not be the bottleneck, correct?